# Using JavaScript array splice() in one line and two lines got different result

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

Code 1:

```
let targetArr = ["hello", "world", "my", "name"];
let errnewArr = Array.from(targetArr).splice(2, 1);
console.log("errnewArr array : " + errnewArr.length);
```

Code 2:

```
targetArr = ["hello", "world", "my", "name"];
let newArr = Array.from(targetArr);
newArr.splice(2, 1);
console.log("new array : " + newArr.length);
```

As you can see, the two code samples have similar logic. Just the splice method is place after the `Array.from` or in a `newArr`, but the result is very different. The `errnewArr` got the length: 1, but the `new array` got the length: 3.

Why does the result look like that?

Comment: `.splice` returns the removed parts of the original array - so the top code outputs the length of the one removed part, the bottom code logs the length of the array with that part removed ... you'd see exactly what's going on if you logged the array instead of the length

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

**splice** returns the deleted elements and change the array in place.

Answer (score -1):

One is the **target** and the other is the **return**

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).